# Не отображаются горизонтальные линии на вкладке активности профиля

Tags: дефект, дизайн, профиль-участника

В профиле участника на [вкладке Активность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) не отображаются горизонтальные линии для вкладок с ненулевым кол-вом оповещений:

> [image: вкладки]

Когда мышь наводишь на вкладку, то полоска появляется:

> [image: в фокусе]

Браузер FF 55.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Firefox 56.0 проблема уже не проявляется.

> [image: Нормальные вкладки]

Может быть, конечно, и на SO что-то пофиксили.

Comment: В моём FF55 проблема всё ещё есть на масштабах <=100%. В хроме тоже есть, но только на масштабе 50%